# Should one use うもれる or うずもれる in this sentence?

Tags: pronunciation

> 現地を踏査した結果、そこには鉱物資源は埋もれていないことがわかった。Having prospected the area, we found no mineral deposits there.

Would you use うもれる or うずもれる for 埋もれる in this sentence?

Comment: This is a tricky question to answer because the うずもれる reading is not taught in Japanese schools and therefore, is not used in the "better" media.

Comment: 私なら、「うもれていない」って読みます・・・

Comment: It's very difficult, I think because this isn't a typical use case for neither うもれる nor うずもれる. Generally these words imply something used to be revealed before it's covered. At least it should be fossil resources...

Answer (score 2):

According to the [dictionary](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/16307/meaning/m0u/), the answer is うずもれる.

> 【３】「うもれる」は、物の中に入り込んで見えなくなる意。

うもれる is used to express that you can't see because it is hidden in the middle of things.

> 【４】「うずもれる」は、土や雪に覆われ、見えなくなる意。

うずもれる is used to express that something is hidden under the ground or under snow.

Answer (score 0):

My personal recommendation is using the **[Japanese →　English dictionary.](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/je/5883/meaning/m0u/)**

Here you can find many examples, so even though 埋｛うず｝もれる and 埋｛う｝もれる
is translated using the English word, "be buried",

it seems 埋｛う｝もれる has a nuance of, even though when something is "under",
the "depth" is shallower than 埋｛うず｝もれる, which as 駑馬十駕 san says, 
like, "in the ( very ) middle of the things".

So that I think in your case 埋｛うず｝もれる would sound better since as I said above, minerals are not "covered in the snows, gravels.

Thank you.

Comment: I got confused sorry about that.